# OS Translator II Installation issue on QGIS 3.16

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install OS Translator II plugin on QGIS 3.16; but I'm getting error as soon as I click on OS Translator link.
[image]

[image]

Is there any way we can install this plugin into qgis to import raster maps into PostGIS db?

Comment: Tested on QGIS 3.26 without issue - its possible your QGIS version (3.16) is too old, so you may need to upgrade.

Comment: Yes It was QGIS version issue. it's working on QGIS 3.24. thanks for your advice